# Jquery não funciona com o <input> carregado com Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

A função jQuery funciona normalmente mas ao incluir o `input ajax` o jQuery não funciona para o `input` que foi incluído!

Tenho a função:

```
$('.alerta').on('input', function() { 
    alert('Olá mundo!'); 
})
```

Tenho o `input` número 1 funcionando com a função acima:

```
<div>
    Número 1:<br>
    <input class="alerta" type="text" name="x"/><br><br>
</div>
<div class="div">
</div>
```

Tenho o ajax que inclui o `input` número 2 na `classe="div"`, mas esse não funciona com a função do jQuery.

```
<?php
echo 'Número 2:<br>
<input class="alerta" type="text" name="y"/><br><br>';
?>
```

Comment: Obrigado ficou bem melhor é que sou novo aqui e estou aprendendo ainda a formatar os textos

Answer (score 0):

Tentou colocar assim?

```
$('body').on('click', '#botao', function (e) {
   alert('teste');
});
```

Comment: Obrigado Marcel! Funcionou     
    $('body').on('input', '.alerta', function (e) {
           alert('Olá mundo!');
    });